# Can't connect to service on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I have a service i just installed on a ubuntu workstation machine. Say its running under port 511. I can connect locally :

```
telnet localhost 511
```

When i try to connect from a remote machine it fails

```
telnet 192.168.0.1 511
```

Whats wierd is i tried to connect locally using the ip address and i get the following error:
"Unable to connect to remote host: Connection Refused"

I checked the status of the firewall:

```
sudo ufw status
```

and get back "status:inactive"

So does anyone know why i can't connect remotely since the firewall is disabled and why can't i connect locally using its ip address. I don't know if this matters but its running under esxi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to try (in no particular order):

1. Run `ifconfig -a` on your Ubuntu VM to determine if the assigned NIC has the 192.168.0.1 assigned properly.
2. Run `iptables -L` on your Ubuntu VM to determine if any filters are in place.  This is a "just making sure" type of check.
3. Run `nestat -antup|grep 511` on your Ubuntu VM to determine if the service is listening.  It could be that your service is only listening on the lo interface.